# Cannot log in to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: encryption, password-recovery, ubuntu-mate

I was working on installing duo 2fa for ssh when ubuntu stopped accepting my password. According to passwd I have it correct, but nothing else accepts it. I tried to reset it and it said it was successful. When I try to log in with the old password it shows a yellow box that just says Password. Any other password is incorrect.
My home directory is encrypted and I know both the password I enter at boot and the key it gave me. Now my only goal is to get the files from my home directory. I went into ubuntu recovery and created a new sudoer user and set the owner of my home directory to that user (which probably did nothing). I also set the password. When I try to log in, that password is also always incorrect.
When I tried to access my disk with a live usb or even the root user (even with the fs in read/write) I always get the standard two files-readme and the access-your-private-desktop.desktop thing.

Thanks for reading and please help me. Again, my only goal at this point is to get those files back. A bonus would be the whole user. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Install KUser and rund it as superuser. Now you can enter a new password for any user.

```
If your using KDE environment you can use: kdesudo kuser
If your using Gnome use: gksudo kuser
```

Comment: (gksudo:1661): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: Have look here, it may hold the answer to your problem: http://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi

Comment: Alright, I got in to my user, but it almost looks like I'm the root user now. My home folder has the normal default folders (desktop, etc) but then it has the dang access-your-private-desktop.desktop file. I also installed arch over the drive with grub, so now it looks like I cannot even boot ubuntu. Now I only have the drive.

Comment: In that case, open kuser again and see wich groups are assigned to you. You should NOT be in the group "root". If you can't get it fixed, create a new standard user and delete the old one. You may want to make a backup of your homefolder first, so your profiles for your browser, email etc. aren't lost.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if that stuff is lost and if my user is messed up. The only thing I care about at all at this point is one folder on my desktop. If I get that singe file off my encrypted hard drive, the rest will get deleted anyway: I'm done with ubuntu. Is there any way to do this from another OS, such as arch? GRUB was deleted. :(

Comment: Have you tried to actually login as root? Or at least start a superuser session? You'll have to activate your root account first as it is disabled in ubuntu by default. As root you should be able to access anything on the harddrive. You should find all homefolders in ´/home´. Though I can't be 100% sure about encrypted folders. I'd still bet my money on resetting the password via kUser. Make sure you have your caps turned off. This often causes password problems.

Comment: Nope. Root wouldn't show anything and now I can't use kuser because it won't boot up. I have to manually boot

Comment: Sorry, been away for a couple of days. Do you have the rootpassword? In that case, when you see the boot menu choose de `Advanced options for Ubuntu` (of whatever flavor it mentions, just make sure you got the advanced options). Then choose one of the top options in `Recovery mode`. You may see that option more than once if you've had kernel updates. Just pick the one with the highest version number. You then get a screen with options. One of them is named `root` with a leading text like `Drop to root shell prompt`.

Comment: You're then asked to provide the root password, after which you end up at the textprompt and a cursor. Now you enter the following command: `ls /home` to check the correct spelling for the user. Then enter `passwd <username>`. This prompts you to enter a new password for the user whoms name you just entered. Then you're promted to repeat the password. After this you enter `exit` to revert to the menu where you can then choose the top entry to resume booting normally. After this the account should be accessible. If not, I'm lost too...

Comment: I almost forgot. Before you try to set the new password,  you have to set the filesystem to read/write. You do this with the following command: `mount -o rw,remount /`

Comment: `So to recapitulate:` Start your machine and at the bootmenu choose: `Advanced options for Ubuntu` then choose the first option which includes `(Recovery mode)`. In the following menu choos the option names `root`.  Enter your root password and then enter `mount -o rw,remount /`. Now enter `ls /home` check the username you need and use that with the command `passwd <username>`. Substitute <username> with the required username and keep in mind that linux is very picky in using small- and large caps, so write the username exactly as it was shown.

Comment: Now enter a new password followed by an `Enter` and repeat the password to check for typos.  If all is accepted (no errors) type `exit` and choose `resume` in the following menu. Just hit `Enter' until you see the system is booting into linux. If your sytem doesn't work correctly, some drivers may have been missed in this procedure. So just reboot once more to correct that.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to set the root drive in grub and am getting an error. All I have now is the drive. Before the bootloader was wiped, I actually accessed my account. All the files in my account that I logged in to were wiped. It was set up like a new user except it had the private desktop files. I logged in to the correct user and I believe it was the only home directory on the computer,

Comment: I also attempted to use a file recovery tool on my other os but it only recovered useless system files.

Comment: Well, if all files are wiped, there's no need to try and get access anymore, now is there...

Comment: Well, that was stated badly. They seem to be wiped

Comment: I'm not sure about your current situation. As I see it, your bootloader is gone. Can you still boot into Ubuntu? Or is that option unavailable? Or is Ubuntu removed from your system. I don't want to rewrite something that's already been written elsewhere, (mainly because it's a lot of information), so have a look at the following page to reïnstall your bootloader. either from windows, from Ubuntu or from a Live-CD:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System`

Comment: After doing this you may want to try the solution a mentioned above (booting into recovery). If that doesn't work, I'm out of options here. Sorry...